# How low would a full revolution around Titan and Triton be possible?

Tags: orbit, atmospheric-drag, titan, triton

A lowest circular orbit to remain stable around the Earth is possible at an altitude of about 95 mi (155 km) while the lowest perigee for a stable elliptical orbit around the Earth would be around 55 mi (88.5 km). I'd like to know these values on the moons Titan and Triton.

Titan's atmosphere reaches very high, and I suppose a stable circular orbit around Titan isn't possible below 500 mi (805 km). Triton's atmosphere on the other hand is very weak but still a more essential one, and you can't orbit Triton just above the surface (like you could above Mercury and many moons) while in [Orbiter2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbiter_(simulator)) I approached Triton as close as 33 mi (53 km) above its surface and my spacecraft's instruments still didn't show any air pressure nor any dynamic pressure at all. On Triton's surface my spacecraft would show an air pressure of 1.45 pa.

What would be the lowest possible circular orbit and the lowest possible perigee around Titan and Triton?

Comment: I would say nothing is stable forever. Th elower you go the more atmosphere (if any). Thus I think a btter question would be 'how low could a perigee or orbit be when stable for $time period'.

Comment: @Hennes The question is for one stable orbit (one full revolution around the body).

Comment: One orbit - doesn't count as stable...

Comment: @RoryAlsop One orbit that counts as stable, meaning the orbiter continues its flight and may or may not enter the atmosphere during the 2nd orbit / at its 2nd perigee.

Comment: I've adjusted my question to be more clear.

Comment: Ok, quite a lot clearer. But a good answer would need to involve the mass of the object (heavier things are harder to slow down) and the surface area facing the direction of travel. So there will not be any one single answer unless it includes a formula.

Comment: @Hennes Whatever a satellite, probe or crewed spacecraft would weigh. Let's say a mass of 100 lb (45 kg) but it's really up to the answerer. I'm asking for an approximate altitude, not one precise to the inch. What do you mean by "surface area facing the direction of travel"?

Comment: The atmossphere has no hard border. There is no place where you caqn breathe and then suddenly a place where you cannot. It just gradually thins out. So your satelite would have friction with the air, which eventually brings it down. The larger the area, the more friction.

Comment: @Hennes Actually there _is_ a kind of sudden border of what you're describing: the Armstrong limit. :-) But back to the topic: as I understand you, what you're referring to is the area of the orbiter, so let's say its area (or size, 2-dimensionally) is 20 ft² (6 m²). Though I think it would be better to note its volume rather than area but you can conclude its volume from its area anyway.